# How to update rows data with the same row name?

Tags: android, sql, arraylist

In my app i have a arrrayList of dataBase and i want to update the whole rows with spacific name : exmaple 
i hava a table like this

1. GENDER | AGES | STREET
2. male---------- 15-------- st.
3. female---------20-------     st.
4. male-----------30-------     st.

i want to update data only if the gender is of "male".

```
public void addSetting(Persons p){
        try {
            open();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

            cv.put(GENDER, p.getGender());
            cv.put(MY_AGE, p.getAges());
            cv.put(MY_STREET, p.getStreet());



            myDb.update(TABLE_SETTING, cv, null, null);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }finally{
            close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean update every row where GENDER = male? If I'm right try this:

```
public void addSetting(Persons p){
        try {
            open();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

            cv.put(GENDER, p.getGender());
            cv.put(MY_AGE, p.getAges());
            cv.put(MY_STREET, p.getStreet());

            myDb.update(TABLE_SETTING, cv, GENDER + " = ?", new String[] { "male" });


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }finally{
            close();
        }
    }
```